# How do I move a UISlider to a postion from within custom class file

Tags: iphone, ios6, uislider

I'm sorry if I'm not asking this clearly...I'm pretty new to XCode. Will do my best.

I am creating a custom UISlider that has three values, 1,2, and 3. I've seen the posts on how to send a UISlider to a position, using something like:

```
[mySlider setValue:2 animated:YES];
```

My question is, how do I do this from within a custom class for my UISlider? I've tried:

```
[self setValue:3 animated:YES];
```

But this doesn't work from inside the custom class file. Can anyone possibly enlighten me as to what I may be doing wrong.

I'm basically using an if statement within an *endTrackingWithTouch* in the custom class looking to see the value of the slider upon touch up, and sending it to either the far left center or far right position.

And again if I am not providing enough detail, or asking clearly enough I apologize.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a custom class? so have you set the slider in IB to your custom class ?

[image]

Also make sure the property is set to your custom slider

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MySliderClass *MySlider;
```

then within your custom slider class, this will work

```
self.value = 1;
```

This is the custom slider class

```
#import "MySliderClass.h"

@implementation MySliderClass

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        //[self setTheSlider];
        // these both work
        //self.value = 1;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setTheSlider
{
    self.value = 1;
}

@end
```

To set the slider from outside the class is what you will need, add this to the header file

```
- (void) setTheSlider;
```

Then from your viewController do this

```
[self.MySlider setTheSlider];
```

Comment: Still can't seem to get this to work. I have that property set to my custom slider in my view controller implementation file. My slider is set to my custom class. In my CustomClass, I have the method "endTrackingWithTouch" and the statement "self.value = 1;" but no dice...any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to call the setTheSlider function from within the custom class though? So I don't have to write a separate line of code for each slider in my view controller?

Comment: Ah...now I get it. Thank you! Sorry...just getting started w Objective-C

Comment: Another question... In what file are you setting the property    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MySliderClass *MySlider; ?

Comment: in the view controller class

Comment: Hi again Smick. Thanks for your help...I am starting to wonder if I'm cut out to be an iOS dev! I still haven't been able to get this to work. If I put self.value = 1; inside my initWithFrame in my custom slider, nothing happens... If I write it in a function as you have above, and call it from my VC, I get the error that property CustomSlider is not found on object of type VC. Any other ideas before I give up altogether!? Thanks so much!!

Comment: upload your project and ill have a look - easier that way. Second, this course is free and just starting and you should do it for sure. https://itunes.apple.com/au/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

Comment: Thanks for that! I will definitely go through that course starting today! Here is a link to a zip of my project. With any luck, I'm missing something really obvious: http://firewalkcreative.com/dropbox/SliderPositionTest.zip Thanks again!!

Comment: A few issues, the major one is you are not using the name of the slider. The slider is called self.mySlider, not self.CustomSlider (line 23). Also use lower case for names of variables. Them in the slider class uncomment out [self setTheSlider]; so it can call the method. Under that comment out the self.value = 1. Do that and all will be sweet. But follow that course and you will learn a lot. Also upgrade to Xcode 5.

Comment: Ahhh brilliant..finally! Thanks so much for the help. I just started that course today...I can tell it's going to be incredibly helpful. I'm still running OSX10.7. So just getting ready to upgrade to Mavericks so I can install XCode 5.. Thanks again!!

Comment: I believe I could if I had Mountain Lion...but apparently 10.7 is not compatible.